# WebApi 2 routing with ? or /

Tags: c#, routes, query-string, asp.net-core-webapi

I just added swagger to my api to generate some documentation...

normally, my front end code would do a "get by id" like this:

https://whatever.com/api/GetDisplayContainer/A90555CD-931E-4D9D-D51D-08D63E83FCC6

however, swaggers "try it" wants to send:

https://whatever.com/api/GetDisplayContainer?id=A90555CD-931E-4D9D-D51D-08D63E83FCC6

I want to be able to support both ways. How do I do it?

Here is an example of a controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetDisplayContainer")]
public ApiResponse<ContainerDisplayViewModel> GetDisplayContainer(Guid id)
{
    return ApiResponse.Convert(ResourceService, _containerService.GetDisplayContainerById(id));
}
```

I don't really want to have to change my existing code to do it the "query string" way. because its a totally valid way of doing it. But it would be nice to be able to support both...

This is C# using .net core 2.1.

Thanks!

Comment: If you had your route set as "GetDisplayContainer/{id}" then swagger would probably suggest the format you want

Comment: this works - thanks! if u suggest it as an answer, i will mark it as accepted..

Comment: What happened to the 500 error?

Comment: i realised it was caused by there not being a valid session, once i logged in it worked as expected through the swagger ui, so it was a red herring...

Answer (score 2):

You can do two routes:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetDisplayContainer")]
public ApiResponse<ContainerDisplayViewModel> GetDisplayContainer([FromQuery] Guid id)
{
}
```

and

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetDisplayContainer/{id}")]
public ApiResponse<ContainerDisplayViewModel> GetDisplayContainerRoute([FromRoute] Guid id)
{
}
```

Comment: so the only way is to have a duplicate of every get method that takes a parameter? that seems kind of bad...

Comment: Yes, it's not ideal if you have to do more than one route. I'm glad the other solution worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you change your route from `GetDisplayContainer` to `GetDisplayContainer/{id}` then Swagger will know that the parameter is not located in the query string and should generate your desired output.

Full code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetDisplayContainer/{id}")]
public ApiResponse<ContainerDisplayViewModel> GetDisplayContainer(Guid id)
{
    return ApiResponse.Convert(ResourceService, _containerService.GetDisplayContainerById(id));
}
```